# prove $EO=OF$ is there an euclidean solution?

Tags: geometry

$PQ$ is a chord in a circle such that $PO=OQ$

The chords $AB,CD$ are passing throw $O$.

The chords $AD,BC$ are cutting $PQ$ at $E$ and $F$ reciprocally.

Need to prove: $EO=OF$.

If so i solved it in trigonometry but im asking if there is an euclidean solution.
if so, i'd love to see!
thanks.

http://i57.tinypic.com/dexx0y.jpg

EDIT: $O$ is not the center of the circle.

Comment: Is $O$ the centre? A picture would help immensely.

Comment: Your very first line is weird: *of course* $\;PO=QO\;$ as both segments are radius in that circle! What is that "such that" for, then?

Comment: Need a picture.

Comment: $O$ is just to say that it's the center it's not weird (see Sandeep comment).

Comment: Just upload a sketch

Comment: Usually, when one mentions "circle O" it is understood it is a circle with center at a point O ...

Comment: i'll remember that, thanks!

Comment: That sketch you uploaded seems to be wrong according to the given data: O is the circle's center, AB, CD are diameters...and you made PQ **also** a diameter!

Comment: sorry $O$ isn't the center. now all my work is gone:(